# Can I add a 5GHz USB wifi adapter to a tablet that has integrated 2.4 GHZ wifi?

Tags: wireless-networking, usb, adapter, tablet

I have an ASUS z300c tablet running Android 5.0.2 with integrated 2.4 GHz wifi.

Can I install a 5 GHz USB wifi adapter (using a USB to micro USB passive cable) and connect to my 5 GHz capable router?

Hoping this question belongs here rather than on Server Fault,

Andy

Comment: Yes; Just disable the 2.4GHz adapter

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you should be able to use the USB adapter **if it is supported by Android**. You would also want to turn off the 2.4Ghz while using the 5Ghz.  Also if you are not sure if it is supported by Android I would contact the manufacturer.  Not all adapters will be recognized by the Android operating system.  Through rooting and modification of the Android operating system, you may be able to get some unsupported adapters to work.

I am unaware of any WiFi adapter that is just "plug and play".  All require some type of driver or software to function properly. Windows may automatically detect and install this software so you don't have to worry about it, but it is still required and you would need the equivalent for your Android tablet.